# How to plot a sine wave with 10000 points on 2000 pixels?

Tags: math, plot, trigonometry

I'm having an audio buffer filled with a sine wave (44100 samples). Now I would like to plot its graph (or at least the first 10k points) in a window that fits on a 2000px screen.

How do you do that?

My first idea was to plot only every 5th Point (`10000 % 2000`). However, this feels kind of too easy and doesn't look great

Comment: I would suggest condensing five points into each row. Basically, draw a vertical line from the position corresponding to the lowest of the five points to the position corresponding to the highest of the five points.

Comment: ah, so you basically calculate and draw the average value (or better RMS value?) of 5 points as 1 point?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting drawing a vertical line from the lowest value to the highest value.

Comment: ah ok thank you, I will try that